# Making a new class for a matrix in R

Tags: r, class, object, methods, matrix

I have some functions which take very specific matrices with specific information loaded in using another function I've made. Currently the matrices the function accepts are the normal R matrix type. However I'd like to assign them as a different type or class so as to achieve easy input checking so the user can't throw any matrix into the function.

I figured the S3 method would be easy after seeing a few examples on the net:

```
mat1 <- matrix(c(1:10),ncol=5)

colnames(mat1) <- c("ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE")

as.sdpmgdna <- function(x) {
  class(x) <- "sdpmgdna"
  return(x)
}

mat2 <- as.sdpmgdna(mat1)
```

This appears to work in so far as if I return mat2 I see a matrix, and if I call it via indecies mat2[1,2] I get the right values I should get. However I can't be sure some things have changed - it is now described as sdpmgdna[10] i.e. it seems to ignore it has 2 dimensions, although doing the above and printing mat2 to screen shows it clearly does have 2 dimensions. Another odd thing is if I do `colnames(mat2)` they are returned. However if I try to find the colname of an individual column e.g. `colname(mat2[,4])` then the value returned is `NULL`. Can anyone explain why this is or what I should do - I really want it to basically be a matrix, but because the functions require it to be very specific in terms of a matrix of what and how big, defining it as another class would make error and input checking so much easier - and allow me to use the methods mechanism of R so all my custom plotting functions could just be methods of plot().

Comment: You should probably make it `inherit` from `matrix` (see `?class`). Instead of `colnames(mat2[, 4])`, try `colnames(mat2)[4]` or `colnames(mat2[, 4, drop = FALSE])`.

Comment: The inheritance part is easy enough: `class(x) <- c(class(x), "sdpmgdna")`. I'd add that "sdpmgdna" is a pretty bad name for a class - very hard to intuit what it might mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `colnames` to individual column of ordinary matrix you also get `NULL`:

```
colnames(mat1[,1])
NULL
dim(mat1[,1])
NULL
dim(mat1[,1,drop=FALSE])
[1] 2 1
colnames(mat1[,1,drop=FALSE])
[1] "ONE"
```

Other issue is that as your new matrix does not have `matrix` class, methods which would require object of class `matrix` won't work. Better to give also `matrix` as class attribute:

```
isSymmetric(mat2)
Error in UseMethod("isSymmetric") : 
  no applicable method for 'isSymmetric' 
  applied to an object of class "sdpmgdna"
class(mat2)<-c("sdpmgdna","matrix")
isSymmetric(mat2)
[1] FALSE
```

Note that even without matrix class some things work as:

```
class(mat2)<-c("sdpmgdna")
is.matrix(mat2)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You should changes

```
class(x) <- "sdpmgdna"
```

to

```
class(x) <- c("sdpmgdan", "matrix")
```

That way R searchs first for your class methods and if doesn't find them it will use matrix methods

Comment: In case you apply your `as.sdpmgdan` function to a non-matrix, you might want to use `class(x) <- c(class(x), "sdpmgdan")` instead.